# Access objects stored in list

Tags: python, list, class, object

I´m not sure if I have done everything correctly but I want to access objects that I stored in a list. Here is the code:

```
# Obstcale class
class obstacle(object):

    def __init__(self, obstacleImg, obstacleX, obstacleY, obstacelX_change):
        self.obstacleImg = pygame.image.load("rock.png")
        self.obstacleX = random.randint(600, 700)
        self.obstacleY = random.randint(0, ScreenHeight - 64)
        self.obstacleX_change = -0.3

    def spawn_obstacle(self, x, y):
        screen.blit(self.obstacleImg, (x, y))
while running:

    if count < 1299:
        count += 1
    else:
        obstacle_number += 1
        obstacle_list.append(obstacle)
        count = 0
        print(obstacle_list[obstacle_number-1])
```

With the print function I want to print out every new object created by accessing the List but everything i get is this:

```
<class '__main__.obstacle'>
<class '__main__.obstacle'>
<class '__main__.obstacle'>
<class '__main__.obstacle'>
<class '__main__.obstacle'>
<class '__main__.obstacle'>
```

Comment: "I want to print out every new object created" - you created zero new objects in that loop.

Comment: If you want to make instances of `obstacle`, you're going to have to call the class, and you're going to have to fix your `__init__` - it's defined as taking a bunch of parameters it completely ignores.

Comment: `obstacle_list.append(obstacle)` appends the _class_ `obstacle` (not an _instance_ of that class!) to the list. To create instances of classes, you normally use `obstacle(arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. Do you have an idea how I can create an instance of the class every time the count value reaches 1300?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks. Why does it ignore the parameters?

Comment: @TimoMeyer, it depends on what the `obstacleImg, obstacleX, obstacleY, obstacelX_change` parameters in the `__init__` method mean. Basically, you create an instance of a class and invoke `__init__` with the syntax `obstacle(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`, so just like when you're calling a function, but you need to know what these arguments need to be, you need to provide them

Comment: @ForceBru So i could delete the concrete values i wrote in `__init__` and provide these exact values when i create the instance?

Comment: @TimoMeyer, well, if your `__init__` isn't using any of its arguments anyway, maybe it doesn't actually need any arguments? (Except `self`, of course). Then you would create an instance like `obstacle()`.

Comment: @ForceBru Okay. Yeah, I don´t think I need the arguments in the `__init__`, but I need them in the `def spawn_obstacle()` because I need the coordinates to spawn the obstacle. My idea is to just move the arguments to this function because thats where I need them. But what to I write into the `__init__` if there only is `self`?

Comment: @TimoMeyer, absolutely nothing - you just say `obstacle()` to create the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Create actual instances of your class.  Defining a `__repr__` (debug representation) to make a meaningful display of the instance helps, too.  Below is your code modified into a minimal, reproducible example creating a short list of Obstacles:

```py
import random

ScreenHeight = 600

class Obstacle(object):

    def __init__(self): # removed unused parameters
        self.obstacleImg = 'rock.png' # pygame.image.load("rock.png")
        self.obstacleX = random.randint(600, 700)
        self.obstacleY = random.randint(0, ScreenHeight - 64)
        self.obstacleX_change = -0.3

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Obstacle(image={self.obstacleImg!r}, X={self.obstacleX}, Y={self.obstacleY}, change={self.obstacleX_change})'
    
obstacle_list = []
while len(obstacle_list) < 5:
    obstacle = Obstacle()  # call the class to create an instance
    obstacle_list.append(obstacle)
    print(obstacle)
```

```
Obstacle(image='rock.png', X=650, Y=62, change=-0.3)
Obstacle(image='rock.png', X=677, Y=8, change=-0.3)
Obstacle(image='rock.png', X=625, Y=370, change=-0.3)
Obstacle(image='rock.png', X=642, Y=536, change=-0.3)
Obstacle(image='rock.png', X=688, Y=311, change=-0.3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot :)

Comment: How does this show how to access  objects stored in the list exactly? All i see at the end is a `print(obstacle)` which just prints the newly created object, it's not actually accessing the objects in any list?

Comment: @slm `obstacle_list` is the list, but the OP’s problem was creating instances of the items and displaying them properly. `print(obstacle_list)` if you want to see the final result.